# Where do the photons go in polarized filters?

Tags: optics, visible-light, photons, polarization

If a pair of oppositely polarized (v/h) filters are put together, no light photons get through, so if all light photons incident on such a setup get reflected, the setup would

a) be a perfect mirror,

or if all the photons get absorbed in the filters, the filters should

b) heat up more and more.

Is a) the case or how hot do the filters get?

Comment: Why not get a couple of polarizing filters and do the experiment?

Answer (score 5):

Common polarizing filters absorb the radiation they don't transmit. They get as hot as any similar object absorbing the same power in the situation they are in (air flow, ambient temperature, ...).

Answer (score 3):

Both reflecting and absorbing polarizers exist. If a beam is incident on an absorbing polarizer with power $P$ of the incorrect polarization then the polarizer will heat up at a rate of $P$ Watts per second. The polarizer is heat sunk to its mount and to air (if the polarizer is on Earth and not vacuum sealed) so this thermal energy is dissipated out of the optic. Without know a lot of details about this heat sinking it’s impossible to translate input power absorbed into a direct temperature increase.

Maybe a more thorough answer could be given if you have more details about why you want to know how much the polarizer heats up.

Or if your question is really just: “do absorbing polarizers really actually heat up?” Then the answer is “Yes.”

Answer (score 1):

### In the visible range

As answered by John Doty the most common polarizing filters in the visible range *absorb* one of the polarizations, letting the other pass. So two in a row will each absorb half of the intensity of the light.

There are polarizers that do not absorb one of the components but redirect it (e.g. the [Nicol prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicol_prism) based on birefringence), or ones based on Fresnel reflection (where all reflected light is polarized when the incident angle is the Brewster angle of the material).

Those kinds of devices result in two polarized "beams" (the reflected beams in Fresnel based polarizers require careful engineering to line up), and one of those beams is sometimes dumped in an absorber (= a matte black box), but sometimes it is used as a beam splitter.

However, putting those in a line won't result in a mirror, as they don't reflect the light back to the source.

### Radio Waves

For radio waves and microwaves you can construct [wire grid polarizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer#Wire-grid_polarizers). Those typically transmit one polarization, while mostly reflecting the other one, so two of those in a row would act as a mirror (although not as a perfect mirror, as a phase delay between the two polarization components is introduced in such a setup if the distance between them is not small compared to the wavelength).

(Two perpendicular ones of those in contact are effectively a mesh, and a mesh with a mesh width small compared to the wavelength will act like a metal sheet – think of a Faraday cage).